# Does the OP of a flagged post get comment notifications if the post is deleted by mods?

Tags: support, comments, flags

When I flag new user posts for "Not an answer" or "me too" type stuff, I usually write a comment to the user asking him to post a separate question  and don't pollute the universe bla bla.

Now I can see later - the post was deleted by a mod, but will the OP receive my comment if he logs in after a while - since the post is deleted.

Examples (I assume 10Ks can see the deleted posts - I'm not sure if these are the ones I commented on, but I flagged these for deletion)

[Mumps Syntactical conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298690/mumps-syntactical-conflicts/5470608#5470608) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940607/iphone-openflow-orientation-issue/5472990#5472990

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments on deleted posts are removed from the user's inbox when the post is deleted; the exception is when a moderator posts the comment and then deletes the user's post within an hour, for exactly the case mentioned in the question.

A recent feature change also allows users to see their own deleted questions, as long as they saved a link to them (the question won't show up in their profile or any question lists).

The user won't have an inbox notification, but if they still have a link to the question they'll be able to see it on the post.