# Can non-10k users see comments left on their deleted content?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, deleted-posts

I ask partially in relation to [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158439/152134), but also for my own use;

My question is, if I leave a comment on a question or answer that is subsequently deleted, does the (non-10k) poster get a notification, if they arrive on the site after the content has already been deleted? And if so, can they then view the content?

I often leave what I hope are helpful comments when I flag content for deletion, especially for borderline spam and for non-answers. Very often, the user won't return to the site before the content is deleted, though.

So, is this practice at all helpful to the OP?

Comment: for an [answer deleted by owner](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/112746/31260 "Programmers.SE example - 10K only link"), the answer to your question is definitely yes: here is a screen shot of **[how it looks like for a particular non-10K user (yours truly)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AVo7x.png)**

Comment: I believe that the owner of a post can always see the post, even if it's been deleted. That means they can see any undeleted comments on it. Only diamond moderators can see deleted comments and only 10k users can see deleted posts that they don't own. However, I'm not confident enough to post that as an answer...

Comment: @ThomasOwens You are correct. Why not post that and someone can edit in whether editors to the deleted post can see it as well as the OP - but for sure the author of any post sees deleted content just like Moderators and 10K+ users. Even diamond moderators have to ask to see deleted comments - they view for a deleted post is uniform for all who cross the threshold to see it in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The owner of a deleted answer can always see the post and comments made to it, minus any author- or moderator- deleted comments. If you are able to post a comment and the post gets deleted, as long as the comment isn't deleted, the author of the post will be able to read it. Questions are a different story — these are only visible to 10k users.

10k users can view all deleted posts along with any comments attached to them, again minus any deleted comments. If you at-reply a 10k user and the post gets deleted, they will be able to read the comments.

Diamond moderators have the same view as a 10k user, by default. However, diamond moderators can also view all of the deleted comments through mod tools.

The only time your comment on a deleted post won't be visible is if you at-reply a user who does not have 10k and they don't read the comment before the post is deleted.

Comment: Just to point out as well that even mods don't have edit history of comments.

Comment: Sounds like there's actually *two* cases, not just one, where comments will be invisible: asker's-question deletion, and unrelated-post deletion.