# When a user gets a post deleted by a moderator, does he still get notifications on the comments left on it during his absence?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-answers

#### The real duplicate is: [How do notifications on deleted posts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231668/209901)

Say someone joins a site in Stack Exchange and posts an answer. That answer is not good enough, so it gets some comments to finally be deleted by a moderator. The user has not been active on the site during all of this, so no notifications arrived to him before the question got deleted.

After few days, the user enters the site again and his answer is gone. However, is he still able to see the comments that were written to him, as well as to see his initial post and update it? More importantly: does he get the notifications on the comments? (which is something not covered in any of the targeted duplicates).

This is relevant to me since in a site I mod we some times have the case of someone posting an answer that can be a hidden gem, but needs quite a lot of polishing. This is a common case in Spanish Stack Exchange: a very basic answer consisting in a mere translation, that could somehow get improved by the author by adding some references and examples. It is more a comment than an answer, so it does not deserve to be kept there, but if the author dares to do some extra work on it, it will be very useful.
I do want the user to get our feedback in comments, so I wonder if it is lost if the post gets deleted.

It would be also interesting to know if such behaviour is the same for users with reputation 1 (brand new users) and reputation 101 (trusted users in other sites).

Comment: Deletion is generally for posts that *can't* be salvaged, not as a temporary state to improve posts

Comment: @fedorqui [Can non-10k users see comments left on their deleted content?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158441/310998)

Comment: Quote from the faq linked in the first comment: *Deleted posts that are no more than 60 days old (since the creation date) are listed under "recent deleted questions" or "recent deleted answers".* So if the user is aware of this possibility, they might be able to *find* their deleted content. (Although they would have to actively search for it.)

Comment: @Martin yes, I am aware of it. However, for a brand new user is quite unlikely that they know how to get there. That's why I rewrote my question to address the key topic (to me): does he still get the notifications about the comments left on the post?

Comment: Answer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231668/how-do-notifications-on-deleted-posts-work) says that: "Only comment notifications to the OP left by the deleting moderator within that last hour will remain in the inbox."

Comment: @Martin this is the exact answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And since you mention that you are asking since it is important to you as a moderator, the last part of that answer seems to be relevant, too: "Commenting on a deleted answer would indeed keep the notification, which is reasonable as only moderators can comment on deleted posts and users can see their own deleted posts." (Sorry for double ping, I only notice this additional detail now.)

Comment: @Martin no problem :) This is very interesting. It is a pity though that the notification just lasts for one hour (in [spanish.se] we have users entering once in a big while). Regarding the last part, I do not know if it effectively works: I recently wrote a comment in a deleted question in Meta and I did not see any input in the "responses" tag from that user (which is a tag moderators can see in a user profile). Maybe the user did get a notification, this I don't know.

Comment: @fedorqui I might have misunderstood the answer, but I thought that *last part* hour meant that notification will be received if the comment was posted less then an hour before the post was delete. It does not matter how soon the user will get to the site to read the notifications. In any case, the answer describes some situations when the notifications should work (assuming it is not outdated). So perhaps you can find some volunteer to test this on the site where you are a moderator (or on the associated meta).

Comment: @Martin Oded just clarified it and it is the way you said! Thanks :)

Comment: @Shadow would you mind adding [How do notifications on deleted posts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231668/209901) to the list of duplicates?