# Moderator deleted an answer. How we know what was his reasons for?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, deleted-answers

There is a question on StackOverflow posted today (Apr, 26th) that I flagged as duplicate of another question (answered Feb '11), have barely the same question.

At any rate, I've answered the question, providing both the answer to his specific case and pointing the url of the duplicated question.

My answer had already 3 upvotes and a moderator deleted my answer and did not flagged as duplicated.

Just for the sake of examples, [here is the today's question (duplicated IMO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244903/how-to-remove-span-and-div-that-does-not-have-class-or-id) and [here is the 2011 one (already pointing to the correct answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991576/select-elements-without-any-class/4991591#4991591).

And the deleted answer was:

> Mostly duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/a/4991591/684932
>
> In your example, this will work: `$('div > span:not([class])').remove();`

**So the question is:**

*How can we know what were the reasons for the deletion?*

I've read some questions about this and normally the other moderators answered that they normally post a comment explaining before delete. This wasn't the case.

Comment: It was a link only answer, and was arguably plagiarism (from my brief look).

Comment: Its not link only, i've posted the code as well. The code is one line only and if you note, I added the "div >" to the query, which increases the selector specificity for that question's provided html. And all answers were given more or less on the same time (when i was writing, that 'new answers' alert had poped)

Comment: Not only that, I had 3 upvotes which seems other users liked it more than the others at the time of answer. But anyways, the link points to a more detailed answer. Since the questions ARE duplicated (same question, just that one have a wrapper div, the other dont), normally giving a "detailed" answer would then be plagiarism (of the first question, considering the notice that appears before the question with a link to the other one when a question is flagged as duplicated)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's a duplicate, flag it as a duplicate instead of posting an answer that simply points to the duplicate. If you cannot vote to close but you can post comments, you can always post a comment pointing to the duplicate.

While this isn't plagiarism in the strict sense of the word, if you're not going to post your own answer in spite of the fact that it is a duplicate, it's generally a good idea to avoid posting an answer at all, as it's often seen as bad form to simply lift other answers from elsewhere if a question is already answered there. The basic principle behind this is that if we already have duplicate questions, then there is generally no reason to have to duplicate their answers as well.

> I've read some questions about this and normally the other moderators answered that they normally post a comment explaining before delete. This wasn't the case.

This depends on the site. On Stack Overflow, I'll admit we don't often post comments before deleting answers, but that's simply because we have so many flags that it's just not feasible to have to post a comment on every single answer that we delete in response to a flag (which is the case here). For example, if it's something obvious, we don't comment unless the user is particularly new.

That said, we do have requests here on meta for addressing certain limitations to comments with regard to deleting/deleted answers. For one, [we cannot comment on an answer after deleting it unless we undelete it first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158439/allow-diamond-moderators-to-comment-on-deleted-or-locked-items). That's as much an inconvenience for us as it is for users.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that one of having to undelete first. Quite annoying for mods, I agree. Anyways, I've flagged as duplicated. Normally I flag only. But all the questions I flagged, my flags were completely ignored, since the duplicate text don't even mention me (in this example, flagged 21 hours ago)  `marked as duplicate by gaige, Derek 朕會功夫, Cole Johnson, Jean-Bernard Pellerin, Pieter Geerkens 14 hours ago` . Thanks for your answer, will not add an answer on duplicated anymore. But I often see people getting points for the duplicated answer before getting flagged (and their answer kept).

Comment: Anyways, I wonder why I got deleted while other people were kept. I like the randomness.