# Moderators can no longer comment on deleted posts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

I'm fairly certain we recently got this ability; [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158439/allow-diamond-moderators-to-comment-on-deleted-or-locked-items) was marked status-completed last month, and two other moderators confirmed for me that I'm not going crazy and we used to be able to do this. But those moderators (and myself as well) seem to have lost this ability now.  I no longer see the "add comment" option on deleted posts on the site I moderate. Is this a mistaken casualty of the close options update, or is something else going on?

Comment: ThisFeatureWasImplemented != YouNotGoingCrazy, just FYI ;)

Comment: @WendiKidd I lied--I can't do it anymore either (Meta or Main), but it was working two days ago.

Comment: @simchona Aww, and here I was thinking we'd narrowed it down some! :)  Yeah, I did it a few days ago too; it seems to have broken since the new close reasons were implemented network-wide. Could be a coincidence I suppose, but perhaps not :)

Comment: This went away for me too. It was working on C.SE at least 2 days ago, as of today it is not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wendi - quite right, with all the close changes we had a regression here :(

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Deleted - does this work?

Comment: Undeleted - yes it does now. Phew!