# Let mods upvote comments on deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools

Normally, a user cannot add a comment or upvote a comment on a deleted post. This is fine and good. A moderator, however, [can add comments to deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185876/202832). However, moderators are still unable to upvote a comment on deleted post. I believe this would be a helpful feature to have because showing more agreement to a previous comment can also be powerful.

Comment: +1 because it's cool feature but -1 because I don't really agree with this idea. If going this way, let anyone seeing the comments upvote them. (i.e. 10k'ers, OP etc)

Comment: I'm not sure I buy the "upvoting a comment can be more powerful".  The diamond itself carries a lot more weight than a simple comment upvote.  A comment by a mod is worth a lot more than anything else to explain actions (which I think are the main reason commenting on deleted posts is allowed).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Who knows a mod up voted a comment and not just me (a humble normal user)?

If you want to add weight to a comment, the best ways as a moderator is to do it by commenting (**which you can when a post is deleted!**). Voting is anonymous, and your up vote will be lost in the big pile of votes. No one will ever see its value.