# Are moderators no longer able to add comments on deleted posts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderators, deleted-posts

Moderators used to be able to [comment on deleted or locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158439/allow-diamond-moderators-to-comment-on-deleted-or-locked-items). However I've just noticed I am unable to add a comment to a deleted question on Meta Stack Overflow, as the "add comment" link is disabled (but still visible).

Is this an intentional change, or is it a bug?

I've double-checked that I'm still logged in, and disabled all userscripts.

I'm running Chrome 76 on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: This happens to me on mobile brave browser as well in “request desktop site” mode.

Comment: Not an intentional change. We were doing some work in that area and it sounds like I screwed up permission checks after all. Apologies for the inconvenience, will fix tomorrow morning.

Comment: In case this helps: a few minutes ago I deleted a post and then left a comment, without the intervening page load.  After navigating away and then returning to the page later, I see what Samuel sees.  I know you don't refresh everything "inline" with a deletion; I'm only mentioning this to report that the comment did go through at the server, so whatever it is seems to be entirely client-side (if I understand correctly).

Comment: You're spot-on Monica! I edited the class on the link to "js-add-link comments-link" and it allowed me to add a comment to the deleted post

Comment: @SamuelLiew I love how you can just do that. It feels like cheating...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to SO developer Adam Lear ([ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333308/are-moderators-no-longer-able-to-add-comments-on-deleted-posts#comment1088494_333308)), this was not an intentional change. The devs were doing some work in that area which introduced an error in permission checks. Apologies for the inconvenience; this should be fixed shortly.

Comment: Hrm. I can't add a comment to a rejected migration either: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389322/why-is-stack-overflow-not-general-data-protection-regulation-compliant

Comment: Same bug affects locked posts, @George - should be fixed now.

Comment: @shog9 Thanks, it is fixed. I mentioned it in case it's another test case for the bug being fully fixed.